How to debug WASM code without debug information?
I have a task to analyze the behavior of someone else's WASM code, for which there is no debug information. The code isn't complex, but there's a problem: in Chrome DevTools, you can't view memory by the pointer that the WASM code is operating with (which makes debugging almost impossible).
Since the code isn't mine, I also can't insert logging.
There's a plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pdcpmagijalfljmkmjngeonclgbbannb that is supposed to solve this issue, but it doesn't work.
The question is: is there a way to debug WASM code without debug information and source code with the ability to view memory by pointers?
Ideally with code navigation, the ability to change variable values at runtime, cross-references, etc., but maybe I'm dreaming.
I have already tried using wasm2wat<->wat2wasm and adding logging to output variable values to console.log through imports, but it's extremely inefficient

From The State of WebAssembly: "The most frequently cited ‘need’ was better non-browser integration ... Better debugging support is a very close second". Included is link to this page which has some tips.
